# How to read CSV and generate json/avro file with pig grouped by the values of first column?

Tags: json, apache-pig, avro

I am new to pig and have the following "test.csv":

```
A,Mark,45
A,Joe,42
A,Kyle,43
B,Mike,40
```

I know I can iterate through this and generate a record per row with a FOREACH, but
what I dont know is how can I use pig to iterate and generate two records like the following:

```
{"class":"A",people:[["Mark",45],["Joe",42],["Kyle",43]]}
{"class":"B",people:[["Mike",40]]}
```

Note that each record is essentially "grouped" by the unique value of the first column.
If at all possible, this is another alternative that would work too:

```
{"class":"A",people:[{"name":"Mark","age":45},{"name":"Joe","age":42},{"name":"Kyle","age":43}]}
{"class":"B",people:[{"name":"Mike","age":40}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A = load 'test.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (col1, col2, col3);

B = group A by col1;

C = foreach B generate group, A.col2, A.col3;

store C into 'location' using PigStorage(',');

This will give you required o/p. If you want json format o/p then use org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonStorage() for storing ;